# Gap between subviews of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, subviews, gaps-in-visuals

I have two subviews of UIScrollView. One is textView and other is tableView. I made textview's height flexible based on its content, but I have one problem. If the text in the textview (which is parsed data) is small, there is a big gap between textview and tableview. Or if the text is too large then it covers the tableview. How can I keep the same gap between textview and tableview irrespective of the amount of content of text view? This is all done in IB.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must handle both textview and tableview position dynamically like ur text view height and y-axis is 
y-axis 10; height 40;
now in tableview setframe:cgrectmake(your X coordinate, textview.frame.size.height+20)

so its always show same difference between textview and tableview if your textview height is 60 than tableview y point is 60+20

Comment: After two days suffering I did the same, but I just didn't know whether it was the most efficient way. Thank you though.

Comment: i think this is the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)loadView 
{    
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
    pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
    pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pagingScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * [self imageCount],
                                              pagingScrollViewFrame.size.height);
    pagingScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.view = pagingScrollView;

}

- (CGRect)frameForPagingScrollView {
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    frame.origin.x -= PADDING;
    frame.size.width += (2 * PADDING);
    return frame;
}

- (CGRect)frameForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];

    CGRect pageFrame = pagingScrollViewFrame;
    pageFrame.size.width -= (2 * PADDING);
    pageFrame.origin.x = (pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * index) + PADDING;
    return pageFrame;
}
```